# How to set image size and dimension in Intervention Image package using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image, laravel-5.8, intervention

I'm using the **Intervention Image** package for manipulating the uploaded image before saving it to the server. I have successfully set the dimension of the image, and it's working fine, but I want to fix the image size, i.e., the image generated should be less than equals to ***30KB*** and should have a resolution of ***300*** dpi only.

Here is the code, I'm using to resize the uploaded image:

```
$file = $post->file('profile_image');

$filename = Carbon::now()->timestamp.'_'.$file->getClientOriginalName();

\Image::make($file->getRealPath())->resize(160, 160)->save('uploads/profile/'.$filename);
```

If my concern is feasible with the Intervention Image package, please give me a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try somthing like this

```php
$size = 160;
$img = \Image::make($file->getRealPath())->resize($size, $size)->save('uploads/profile/'.$filename);
while($img->filesize() < "someAmount"){
    $size = (int)$size - 20; // adjust based on your need
    $img = \Image::make($file->getRealPath())->resize($size, $size)->save('uploads/profile/'.$filename);
}
```

> **NOTE** this is not correct answer but it is idea to solve this problem

Comment: Hello Kamlesh, thanks for your response, but how can I set the Image resolution to 300 dip